# Keeping LESS sourceMaps for minified css with cssmin

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, source-maps, grunt-contrib-cssmin

My LESS files are compiled with grunt-contrib-less and corresponding grunt task with the following config:

```
module.exports = {

    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapFilename: 'Content/styles/e-life.css.map'
    },
    compile: {
        files: {
            'Content/styles/e-life.css' : 'Content/styles/common.less'
        }
    }

}
```

Then I procced with cssmin for output css file. I get it minified, but I want to bind source maps from the previous step for the minified css.

```
module.exports = {

    options: {
        sourceMap: 'Content/styles/e-life.css.map'
    },
    all: {
        files: {
            'Content/styles/e-life.css': ['Content/styles/e-life.css']
        }
    }

}
```

The task fails if I mention source map path in options.sourceMap. I see the following in [css-clean docs](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-programmatically):

> sourceMap - exposes source map under sourceMap property, e.g. new CleanCSS().minify(source).sourceMap (default is false) If input styles are a product of CSS preprocessor (Less, Sass) an input source map can be passed as a string.

But i can not understand how to pass this string to the task. Is it even possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`grunt-contrib-cssmin` does NOT let you chain sourcemaps.
Its sourceMap option is true/false only, and will generate a map from the minified css to the original css, not to the original Less, sorry.

Considering that source mapping is useful mainly for debugging, I would suggest:

- do not use cssmin in your development environment, that way you get mapping from css to your Less files if needed.
- use cssmin **without mapping** for production.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have decided to go for the second option and use cssmin only for production builds.

Answer (score 1):

You could also avoid the Grunt cssmin task and use the Less compression with `compress` option.

```
module.exports = {

    options: {
        compress: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapFilename: 'Content/styles/e-life.css.map'
    },
    compile: {
        files: {
            'Content/styles/e-life.css' : 'Content/styles/common.less'
        }
    }
}
```

> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#compress